# Step_dummy. Dealing with duplicated column names generated by recipe() steps, Tidymodels

Tags: r, machine-learning, dplyr, recipe, tidymodels

**Dear community,**

I have been struggeling for extensive amount of time now trying to understand what is going on here, when I perform my recipe() steps for my linear (glm) model using the Tidymodels framework. The recipe() step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) was suggested by the usemodels() function https://usemodels.tidymodels.org/index.html .

When I commend out the step_dummy() the recipe() and prep() works fine, however its important to me that these categorical variables are dummyfied (..is that a word!?).

This is the first time I making use of and including a reprex in a question on stackoverflow, so please let me know if you need more information to assist on this matter.

I have looked everywhere, e.g. including a `one_hot = TRUE` or `keep_original_cols` argument in the step_dummy() but it does not seem to be effective.

It should be quite easy as it is a matter of renaming the generated columns as unique, but do not succeed. Here is the era.af_train set.

```
> era.af_train
# A tibble: 7,104 x 44
     logRR    ID AEZ16simple  PrName.Code SubPrName.Code  Product     Country
     <dbl> <dbl> <fct>        <fct>       <fct>           <fct>       <fct>  
 1 -0.851   1663 Warm.Semiar~ BP          TW              Pearl Mill~ Niger  
 2 -1.17    1663 Warm.Semiar~ BP/Mu       Mu-N/TW         Pearl Mill~ Niger  
 3 -0.314   1663 Warm.Semiar~ BP          TW              Pearl Mill~ Niger  
 4 -0.776   1663 Warm.Semiar~ BP          TW              Pearl Mill~ Niger  
 5 -0.0850  1675 Warm.Semiar~ AP          TPM+N           Pearl Mill~ Niger  
 6 -0.159   1689 Warm.Subhum~ Al/AP/BP    Al+N/LF/TP/TPM~ Maize       Togo   
 7 -0.579   1701 Warm.Semiar~ BP          TW              Fodder (Le~ Tunisia
 8 -0.662   1729 Warm.Subhum~ Al          Al-N/Al+N       Cassava or~ Nigeria
 9 -1.80    1802 Cool.Subhum~ Al/AP       Al+N/TP         Wheat       Ethiop~
10 -1.74    1802 Cool.Subhum~ Al/AP       Al+N/TP/TPI+N   Wheat       Ethiop~
# ... with 7,094 more rows, and 37 more variables: Latitude <dbl>,
#   Longitude <dbl>, Site.Type <fct>, Tree <fct>, Bio01_MT_Anu.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio02_MDR.Mean <dbl>, Bio03_Iso.Mean <dbl>, Bio04_TS.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio05_TWM.Mean <dbl>, Bio06_MinTCM.Mean <dbl>, Bio07_TAR.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio08_MT_WetQ.Mean <dbl>, Bio09_MT_DryQ.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio10_MT_WarQ.Mean <dbl>, Bio11_MT_ColQ.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio12_Pecip_Anu.Mean <dbl>, Bio13_Precip_WetM.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio14_Precip_DryM.Mean <dbl>, Bio15_Precip_S.Mean <dbl>,
#   Bio16_Precip_WetQ.Mean <dbl>, Bio17_Precip_DryQ.Mean <dbl>,
#   Mean_log.n_tot_ncs <dbl>, Mean_log.ca_mehlich3 <dbl>,
#   Mean_log.k_mehlich3 <dbl>, Mean_log.mg_mehlich3 <dbl>,
#   Mean_log.p_mehlich3 <dbl>, Mean_log.s_mehlich3 <dbl>,
#   Mean_log.fe_mehlich3 <dbl>, Mean_db_od <dbl>, Mean_bdr <dbl>,
#   Mean_sand_tot_psa <dbl>, Mean_clay_tot_psa <dbl>, Mean_ph_h2o <dbl>,
#   Mean_log.ecec.f <dbl>, Mean_log.c_tot <dbl>, Mean_log.oc <dbl>,
#   Slope.mean <dbl>
```

I am including the columns ID, AEZ16simple, PrName.Code, SubPrName.Code, Product, Country, Latitude and Longitude as "ID variables", as I wish to compare the glm model later with a random forest model and a XGBoost model.

All help is welcome!
Have a good weekend and
thank you in advance.

```r
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(recipes)
#> Warning: package 'recipes' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'recipes'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step
library(readr)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.0.5

setwd("C:/Users/lindh011/OneDrive - Wageningen University & Research/Internship ICRAF (ERA)/ERA_Agroforestry_WURwork")

era.af_train <- read_csv("era.af_train.csv")
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double(),
#>   AEZ16simple = col_character(),
#>   PrName.Code = col_character(),
#>   SubPrName.Code = col_character(),
#>   Product = col_character(),
#>   Country = col_character(),
#>   Site.Type = col_character(),
#>   Tree = col_character()
#> )
#> i Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.
era.af_train_Tib <- as_tibble(era.af_train)

glmnet_recipe <- 
  recipe(formula = logRR ~ ., data = era.af_train) %>% 
  step_novel(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), naming = dummy_names) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>%
  update_role(ID, 
              AEZ16simple, 
              PrName.Code, 
              SubPrName.Code, 
              Product, 
              Country, 
              Latitude,
              Longitude,
              new_role = "sample ID") %>%
   step_impute_mode(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
   step_impute_knn (all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
   step_impute_knn(logRR) %>%
   step_corr(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
   step_nzv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  
  prep()
#> Error: Column names `SubPrName.Code_AF.N.Al.N.TP`, `SubPrName.Code_AF.N.Al.N.TP.TPM`, `SubPrName.Code_Al.N.In.N`, `SubPrName.Code_Al.N.In.N`, `SubPrName.Code_Al.N`, and 33 more must not be duplicated.
#> Use .name_repair to specify repair.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Could I use `step_string2factor()` instead of `step_dummy()`

Comment: In terms of using reprex, I'd recommend checking out some of the articles, like [this](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html) and [this](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html). The idea is to get other help to be able to help you, by giving them enough information to see what your problem is. The big challenges here are that I don't have your data so I can't run the same code as you.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess of what to try next, I would suggest using `update_role()` **first** before you start changing factor levels, normalizing, making dummy variables, imputing, etc. If variables like `SubPrName.Code` are not a predictor at all but rather only an ID, then I would avoid doing any handling of them at all.

Comment: Thank you @JuliaSilge I see your point! True as I actually don't include `SubPrName.Code` etc.. as predictors, I would not really need to perform any `step_*()` on them.  I did resolve the error when I followed your suggestions. 

However, my question here was also related to the fundamental understanding of how to resolve such an issue, as I can imagine it not to be too uncommon.  

Appreciate your reference to good reprex practice. But how would you then recommend to repruduce this error with "simple" built-in-data?

Comment: This is the output of my recipe() after the changes

`rf_prep <- rf_xgboost_recipe %>% 
+   prep(verbose = TRUE, retain = TRUE)
oper 1 step novel [training] 
oper 2 step dummy [training] 
oper 3 step zv [training] 
oper 4 step nzv [training] 
oper 5 step corr [training] 
oper 6 step lincomb [training] 
oper 7 step normalize [training] 
oper 8 step impute mode [training] 
oper 9 step impute knn [training] 
oper 10 step impute knn [training] 
The retained training set is ~ 1.97 Mb  in memory.`